# Suggest python library for rendering html to pdf files

Tags: python, html, pdf

I am generating a pdf from html template using jinja rendering.
Please suggest a library that can help me render html to PDF.
Current issue : html file size is 400 KB but after rendering pdf file zise is > 20 MB
Also some library generates pdf of same size  of html file that is 400 KB but after rendering the format is not as expected.

Tried using xhtml2pdf pisa library, pdf size is unchanged but formatting is not as expected

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. Questions asking us to find or recommend an off-site resource, like a library, are explicitly _off-topic_ as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: "Tried using xhtml2pdf pisa library, pdf size is unchanged but formatting is not as expected"—this _could_ be on-topic, though. Show us how you tried to use that library and explain how it failed to do what you expect. You can read more about how to ask effective questions on our [ask] page.